# Subsites not found when running Craft 3 on shared hosting

Tags: craft3, multi-site

On most shared hosting, you can't set the webroot. As an alternative, a rewriterule to the web folder can do this.
Could be something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]`.

This works on main sites in Craft 3, but breaks subsites.

[I've found an answer from Brandon Kelly](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/2221#issuecomment-352440927), suggesting to use different indexes.php and loading the correct one via the htaccess. (based on subsite prefix)

Is there a better solution since this date, that might prevent the need for different indexes?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, exactly? You can just rename the `web` folder to be whatever it is on your shared hosting.

Comment: Currently, everything is placed in the webfolder and the htaccess is used to reroute all traffic to the web folder. This works, but causes subsites to return as 404.

Is there a way to fix the rewrite for this? Or should I look into adding everything one folder above the webroot and rename the web folder?